# How can I dynamically create JSON from many dot-separated strings (for example project.owner.name)

Tags: apex, json, dynamic-apex

I have many strings in the custom setting with and without dot-separated field names. For example:

1. id
2. name
3. owner.name
4. owner.id
5. project.key
6. project.owner.name
7. project.owner.id
8. document.owner.parentPerson.name

I want to dynamically create JSON string with all these fields. My expected result is:

```
{  
    "id":"some value",
    "name":"some value",
    "owner":{  
        "name":"some value",
        "id":"some value"
    },
    "project":{  
        "key":"some value",
        "owner":{  
            "name":"some value",
            "id":"some value"
        }
    },
    "document":{
        "owner":{
            "parentPerson":{
                "name":"some value"
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are you trying to query a record given these fields, or you already have it and just want to serialize the values?

Comment: I have values for each field: Map<fieldName, fieldValue>. For example "project.key":"K123". I just want to serialize the values. I tried to use Map<String, Object> and methods of String class. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (cursorily tested) code is the sort of thing I would write:

```
String[] names = new String[]{'k', 'k0.k1'};
String[] values = new String[]{'v', 'vv'};

Map<String, Object> root = new Map<String, Object>();
for (Integer j = 0; j < names.size(); j++) {
    String name = names[j];
    String value = values[j];
    Map<String, Object> m = root;
    String[] parts = name.split('\\.');
    for (Integer i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
        String part = parts[i];
        if (i == parts.size() - 1) {
            // At last part so put value
            m.put(part, value);
        } else {
            // Before last part so put map
            Map<String, Object> mm = (Map<String, Object>) m.get(part);
            if (mm == null) {
                mm = new Map<String, Object>();
                m.put(part, mm);
            }
            m = mm;
        }
    }
}
String jsonString = JSON.serializePretty(root);
System.debug(jsonString);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I changed names.length and parts.length to names.size() and parts.size(), but I got errors("Variable does not exist: m
", "Illegal assignment from Object to Map<String,Object>")
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Chris Been writing JavaScript lately... The edited code above compiles and appears to work.